# android google plus login

Tags: android, google-signin

I can get all data when user is signed in but when user enter his credential through my app like email id and password then it gives null value to name,first  name and last name but only I can get is user id and email id.

```
 gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestProfile()
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

private void signIn() {

        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (opr.isDone()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Got cached sign-in");
            GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
            handleSignInResult(result);
        } else {


            opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                    handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
                }
            });
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);




        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
        if(status==1) {

            callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        }


    }


    void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {

        if (result.isSuccess()) {

            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

            id=acct.getId();
            googleId=id;
            personPhotoUrl = acct.getPhotoUrl();
            if(acct.getPhotoUrl() != null) {
                imageUrl = acct.getPhotoUrl().toString();
            }

            else {
                imageUrl="https://www.tineye.com/query/2abdd40717c034bf2dbcd6a0253b933d2a655920?size=160";
            }
            email = acct.getEmail();
            name = acct.getDisplayName();
            firstName = acct.getGivenName();
            lastName = acct.getFamilyName();


            details=new Details(name, firstName, lastName,email, birthday,imageUrl);
            new GetDetails().execute();
            if(details==null)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("googleId", googleId);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }


        } else {


        }
    }
```